# is it possible to add object at last index if all the first indexes are not filled up by objects

Tags: objective-c

I don't know if it is possible to add object at last index if all the first indexes are not filled up by objects in a `NSMutableArray`. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you exactly mean ? Can you show a code and explain where the problem is ?

Comment: ok i got it where was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.
For more details, look at the documentation.

> Note that NSArray objects are not like C arrays. That is, even though you specify a size when you create an array, the specified size is regarded as a “hint”; the actual size of the array is still 0. This means that you cannot insert an object at an index greater than the current count of an array. For example, if an array contains two objects, its size is 2, so you can add objects at indices 0, 1, or 2. Index 3 is illegal and out of bounds; if you try to add an object at index 3 (when the size of the array is 2), NSMutableArray raises an exception.

Comment: i know that what you are talking about.anyways thanks for your cooperation

Comment: You can always fill NSArray with NSNull objects - if you want to keep index based logic.

Comment: Hi i am having an nsmutablearray like
 NSMutableArray *arr;
i did something like below
NSNull *myNull=[NSNull null];
    for(int i=0;i<10;[self.arr insertObject:myNull atIndex:i],++i);
then i replace all the object with some value
for(int i=0;i<[arr1 count];++i){
[self.arr replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex::i]];
}
where arr1 has some real value
but  my problem is there i am getting 20 objects instead of 10.
It should have been 10.
please let me know where is my problem  and what will be the solution.
thanks in advance